# Writing Files where filename contains "/" in POSIX and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, fs

I need to write a file where the filename for example is : `aa/bb.jpg`
but filesystem creates `bb.jpg` within a folder `aa`.

Comment: can you show us what you are trying so far?

Comment: Well, you can't; `/` is simply not allowed as a character in filenames on POSIX systems.  You'll need to pick a different name.

Comment: Filenames in POSIX can't contain `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the "/" in the file name with ":" solves the issue, it is shown in the file explorer as if filename is "aa/bb.jpg" but the file path has ":" instead

Comment: Other file explorer software may or may not behave the same.

Comment: It seems you are working on macOS. This behaviour is specific to macOS (also known as OSX before macOS 10.12 Sierra). The versions of Mac OS before version 10 used to use `:` as path components separator. OSX (version 10) is Unix based and uses `/` as path separator. The behaviour you mentioned can be observed in Finder and in most (all?) programs included in macOS but some other programs show the real name of the file.